# Retrieve Google Dataflow user defined labels in Google Monitoring & Logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-logging

I'm running a *Dataflow* job using the `gcloud` command with the `--parameters labels='{"my_label":"my_value"}'` parameter in order to set custom labels (which I can see in the *Job Info* panel in the UI).

But unfortunately, I'm not able to retrieve this custom label in the *Logging* stack: I can see the classic *Dataflow* labels (`dataflow.googleapis.com/job_name`, `dataflow.googleapis.com/job_id`, etc.) and the *Resource* ones (`step_id`, `project_id`, `region`, etc.) but not my `my_label` custom label.

Is there something I'm missing or is that label propagation I'm expecting does not exist?

Thanks!

**EDIT** Here is the full command I'm using to run my *Dataflow* job:

```
gcloud dataflow flex-template run "my-dataflow-job" \
      --template-file-gcs-location "gs://$(GCP_BUCKET)/my-dataflow-job/templates/my-dataflow-job.json" \
      --region "$(GCP_REGION)" \
      --parameters tempLocation="gs://$(GCP_BUCKET)/my-dataflow-job/temp" \
      --parameters stagingLocation="gs://$(GCP_BUCKET)/my-dataflow-job/staging" \
      --parameters usePublicIps=false \
      --project "$(GCP_PROJECT)" \
      --worker-machine-type="$(DATAFLOW_WORKER_MACHINE_TYPE)" \
      --num-workers=1 \
      --max-workers=1 \
      --parameters labels='{"my_label":"my_value"}'
```

Comment: Could you provide more details on exactly how you're using gcloud to invoke the Dataflow job?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I edited my question with this information.

Comment: Did you try to use the `additional-user-labels` parameter as it said in the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/flex-template/run#--additional-user-labels

Comment: Does it work when you're launching the job without using flex-templates?

Comment: Same thing happening to me, but I'm not using flex-template. I can see my custom labels in the UI and also they appear in the Billing Exports. They don't appear in the logging though. @robertwb is this some known issue?